Do I need to staple cable for new wire run through a preexisting wall?
I'm adding a 220V outlet to support an AC unit.
I plan on running the cable through the attic then running down the inside of the exterior wall to disconnect box.
There is no way for me to staple the wires being run unless I remove the drywall.

Only need to stable/attach in a wall that is not finished with drywall/covering.

Be sure to support the cable through the attic and where it enters the exterior wall from the attic. Good luck fishing ;-)

The exception you're looking for is NEC 334.30(B)(1).

Nonmetallic-sheathed cable shall be permitted to be unsupported where the cable is fished between access points through concealed spaces in finished buildings or structures and supporting is impracticable.

